# how to reset & change the hash password in asp.net membership provider in MVC

Tags: asp.net, passwords, asp.net-membership, membership

I came accross the code :

```
MembershipUser u = Membership.GetUser();
u.ChangePassword(u.ResetPassword(), "Password"); //where will I get the "Password" from
```

I dont understand how I will
    get the client password as the user has forgotten his old password.
    I want to add a reset functionality which would generate a random password and
    send an email to the particular client which will have the userid and the random generated password. After he/she would be able to change the password.

Comment: What don't you understand? This is setting the users password to "Password". It's just a string that could have been entered anywhere or a hard-coded string that gets emailed to the user before they enter the "change my password" section of the site (from a link in an email perhaps).

Comment: oryt so instead of using "password" , can we use something like: string newPassword = Membership.GeneratePassword(8, 2);  and then pass newpassword

Comment: and for the change password functionality , will it work exactly the same way as encrypted ones or we have to do something else for hash

Comment: by the way this is not MVC specific...

Comment: Yeh but i m implementing the membership provider in mvc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate a random password like this using the [Membership GeneratePassword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.generatepassword.aspx) method

```
string password = System.Web.Security.Membership.GeneratePassword(14, 0);
```

If you need to create your own salt and hash a new password, here is an implementation which does much the same as the membership code:

```
public class Cryptographer : ICryptographer
{
    #region ICryptographer Members

    public string CreateSalt()
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[0x10];
        new RNGCryptoServiceProvider().GetBytes(data);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(data);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Hash the password against the salt
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pass">Plain password</param>
    /// <param name="salt">Salt string</param>
    /// <returns>Encrypted password</returns>
    public string HashPassword(string password, string salt)
    {
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password);
        byte[] src = Convert.FromBase64String(salt);
        byte[] dst = new byte[src.Length + bytes.Length];
        byte[] inArray = null;
        Buffer.BlockCopy(src, 0, dst, 0, src.Length);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, dst, src.Length, bytes.Length);
        HashAlgorithm algorithm = HashAlgorithm.Create(System.Web.Security.Membership.HashAlgorithmType);
        inArray = algorithm.ComputeHash(dst);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(inArray);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: The first one is concise and much better , What abt changing the hash password?

Comment: That is if you need to need to save directly to the database, or if you are making your own provider variation.  You can possibly do without this depending on what you are doing.

Comment: yeh i m saving directly to the db but can the user change the password after resetting it .

Comment: yeah, why not? just reset it to their selection instead of a random password.

Answer (score 1):

The second paremeter of the `ChangePassword` method is a string that reprisents the new password you'd like to use for that user.

You can change this to be any string you want, even an auto generated string that you'll email to the user.

**UPDATE**

To answer your new question, I believe that all hashing of the password etc is handled by the Membership Provider.

If you simply want to reset the users password to a random new value, you might be better using the `ResetPassword` method instead of `ChangePassword`.

This will:

> Resets a user's password to a new, automatically generated password.

Comment: Yeh but The random password will not be a friendly one , What I want is to provide user with password change functionality so that they can change the password to more readable ones,